# Looking for a good title for specific job

Tags: word-choice

A friend of mine is trying to sell his products, but he has no shop for selling them. In this case he want to hire someone for advertising his products by going to shops and stores and convince them to buy the product. He wants to announce this vacancy on his website but he didn't come up with a good job title for this.

Is sales person is a good title for this job or are there any better alternatives?

Comment: Perhaps this could be asked on a business/ management related Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best would be "travelling agent" or, maybe "sales agent"...

Comment: or *salesman*. I usually refer to them as such. *Sales Agent* works for formal occasion I suppose

Answer (score 1):

Your friend can use the title *sales representative*

Answer (score 1):

Traveling Salesperson is the usual term for this position. You could also use 'Commercial Traveler'.

Answer (score 1):

It's not sales -- it's marketing -- and the guy is a 'marketing representative.'

*Job Description for a Marketing Representative* By Joy Turner, eHow Contributor, [ehow](http://www.ehow.com/about_6102134_job-description-marketing-representative.html):

> Marketing, in a general sense, creates awareness of a product, business or service in effort to create a connection between buyer and seller. A marketing representative can be thought of as a liaison between the buyer and seller who supports a broad range of marketing activities, including advertising and promotions.

Answer (score 1):

A thought:

Since ultimately it's to convince shops to buy the product:
why not "Product Negotiator",

Or to grant extra credence:

**Sales Delegate**

**Relationship Manager** (Sales)

Or Product Relations Manager

Irrespective of the TAG, the ad description would get your friend the right guys......